# PHP help. I need a link to be opened in new window

Tags: php, target

I have a CMS that I need to modify. I want the external links to open in a new window `target="_blank"`

Here's the code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->menus as $menu) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $menu->type == 'External' ? $menu->link : "/Index/Content/Id/{$menu->id}" ?>">
```

What I have tried:

```
<?php echo ($menu->type == 'External') ? "{$menu->link} target=_blank" : "/Index/Content/Id/{$menu->id}" ?>
```

All links currently open in target blank. How can i make only the external links open in target blank?

Comment: `<a href="some link" <?= ($menu->type == 'external' ? 'target="_blank"' : '') ?></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making manipulation in the `src` attribute,  make your code more readable:

```
<?php if( $menu->type == 'External' ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $menu->link; ?>" target="_blank">
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="/Index/Content/Id/<?php echo $menu->id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Currently, this line:

```
<?php echo ($menu->type == 'External') ? "{$menu->link} target=_blank" : "/Index/Content/Id/{$menu->id}" ?>
```

Will create a link in this format:

```
<a href="http://example.com target=_blank">
```

Changing it to

```
<?php echo ($menu->type == 'External') ? "{$menu->link}\" target=\"_blank" : "/Index/Content/Id/{$menu->id}" ?>
```

Will fix it and you could use your way to do it, because you're closing the `href` attribute with a double quote (`\"`) and only then add the `target` attribute when echoing the result of the ternary operator - You need to take into account the you're wrapping with `"` the php tag where you echoing the url.

Comment: All links open target blank. How can I make only the external links open in target blank?

Comment: If all links are open in a new window then I suspect `$menu->type` is not being set correctly.  The code @Alon has provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the double quote.  Take a look at your rendered HTML & you'll see the problem.

Comment: Show what he needs to do, don't leave it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo ($menu->type == 'External') ? 
     "{$menu->link} target='_blank'" : 
     "/Index/Content/Id/{$menu->id}"; 
 . '"' ?>
```

This has the effect of closing the double quote that you opened with `<a href="` and putting the target into quotes.  This should solve your problem.